# How to use Oracle SQL Date and Time

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have the following example :

```
select * from my_table
where date between ('19-06-2014 00:00:00,000000000 EUROPE/BUCHAREST') and ('19-06-2014 23:59:59,000000000 EUROPE/BUCHAREST'
```

If I run this query it returns the correct values . What I need is something like this :

```
select * from my_table
where date between ('today - 2DAYS ') and ('today - 1DAY')
```

Do you have any idea how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following solution:

--for one day results

```
select * from my_table where date between sysdate - 2  and sysdate - 1
```

--If you wish to start from the beginning of the day:

```
select * from my_table where date between trunc(sysdate) - 2  and trunc(sysdate) - 1
```

FYI - sysdate referes the current date and substrating value will be counted in terms of day. If you wish to substract 12 hrs, you should substract 0.5.